# What is the proper syntax and usage for ArcGIS "in_memory" workspace?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, in-memory

I am unclear how best to use the `in_memory` workspace in ArcGIS.  The best resource I have found on the subject is from ESRI on [Using in-memory workspace](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000005s000000).  Unfortunately, the help section is not very informative.  Also, there is a post on this site that briefly touches on the subject [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33184/8104) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/15153/8104).

My specific questions:

- What is the proper usage and syntax for using `in_memory` workspace in
  ArcGIS/arcpy based scripts?
- Is `in_memory` workspace the same as, for example, creating a layer
  using `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()`?
- Are there any standards such as deleting `in_memory` workspace at the end of
  the script?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I've been using "in_memory" quite a bit recently.  It can be very useful, as it has the potential to dramatically increase processing speeds for certain tasks, however if you are working with very large datasets, it might cause your program to crash.

You can use "in_memory" to define process outputs... often, if I am performing a task on a feature class, I will copy it to the "in_memory" workspace first:

```
inFeature = r'C:\myDir.gdb\myFeature'
memoryFeature = "in_memory" + "\\" + "myMemoryFeature"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inFeature, memoryFeature)
```

Note that you don't have to concatenate memoryFeature together like I did, you could write it out as "in_memory\myMemoryFeature", I just like doing it that way to switch back and forth between "in_memory" and a physical directory easily.  You can then perform processes on your feature in memory.  When you are done, you can reverse the process to save it back to a directory.

I could be wrong, but I believe it is not the same as creating a feature layer.  feature layers give you access to selection methods and other layer specific operations.  Think of the "in_memory" directory as the vector equivalent to the raster object (raster = arcpy.Raster(myRasterLocation))

To clean up after using "in_memory" simply add the following line of code:

```
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree with @egdetti. It is very useful, very powerful, and significantly speeds up processing. You do not actually need to delete the workspace/layer, however, as it will clean itself up when you close the application. As was mentioned, though, running the arcpy.Delete can be helpful (sometimes necessary) if you find yourself running out of RAM because you have *too much* stuff in the in_memory workspace.

Answer (score 12):

There's not a whole lot to it. There's a magic directory you can access in geoprocessing tools and arcpy cursors named `in_memory`. You'd do something like `arcpy.management.CreateTable('in_memory', 'my_new_table')` or `CreateFeatureClass` to make a new featureclass or table. Then you have a new table in that process with the path `in_memory\my_new_table`, if you're in arcmap it will add a table view to the table of contents named `my_new_table` that you can use as a shortcut to get to it. If it's a temporary in memory table, just use `arcpy.management.Delete(r'in_memory\my_new_table')` when you're done with it at the end of your script.

Answer (score 11):

Slightly off topic, but I think worth pointing out. Firstly I agree with both @JasonScheirer and @egdetti above that `in_memory` can be very useful. The biggest thing to note is that `in_memory` workspace does not support raster data. If this becomes an issue I'd reccomend using the Python [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) module. This won't be as fast, but is more reliable. For example, you could do something like:

```py
import arcpy
import tempfile
import os.path
import shutil

try:
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    temp_gdb = "temp.gdb"
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(temp_dir, temp_gdb)
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(temp_dir, temp_gdb)

    #Some processing...

except Exception, e:
    #handle exceptions here
    print e
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir, True)
```

Comment: arcpy has a way to deal with rasters built in with the arcpy.Raster() method.  By defining a variable such as myRaster = arcpy.Raster("C:\RasteLocation") you create a raster object in memory that can be used in map algebra calculations and various other raster operations easily.  Saving such a raster object is as simple as writing in myRaster.save("C:\SaveLocation").  A very helpful feature that arcpy brings to the table.

Comment: @egdetti Fair call. I'm curious to know how it handles larger datasets though.

Comment: @om_henners Thanks for introducing me to "tempfile".@egdetti another good suggestion to use myRaster=arcpy.Raster()--I'm looking forward to testing it.

Comment: @mbenedetti - the Raster object writes a raster to the arcpy scratch workspace - as late as it possibly can, which allows arcpy to optimize I/O by stacking single-cell processing tools (like "+" for example) into a single execution process, for example. The save() method will force execution of the raster processing.

Comment: @om_henners in_memory supports rasters in ArcGIS 10.1!

Comment: @om_henners arcpy provides a tool to create scratch names, which has advantages in that for example a scratch feature class in a folder automatically has ".shp" added to it. The method is arcpy.CreateScratchName().