# Deleting Multiple Layers using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, error-000622, error-000628

I'm writing an add-in for Arcmap and at the end of it I am left with multiple layers from buffers, joins, and selections. I am trying to delete these layers before the add-in finishes so to keep the number of layers in TOC to a minimum. Below is the piece of code I am using to delete the layers, and the error it raises.

```
f = ['Select_1', 'Join_1', 'Buff_1']
for x in f:
    arcpy.Delete_management(x)
```

**Error:**

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
> line 2, in    File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 4359, in
> Delete     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute
> (Delete). Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000628: Cannot set input
> into parameter in_data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may be interested in the [`RemoveLayer`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/removelayer.htm) function in the mapping module. Or specify that intermediate layers should not be added to the TOC.

Depending upon your workflow, you may be able to use [`in_memory`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) workspace to manage intermediate data. Here is a [post on GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/88534/8104) that addresses managing intermediate data with [`in_memory`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) workspace.